# Minimum wins needed to advance into

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Let's say we have $16$ teams and the teams are divided into two groups of $8$ teams each.
Each team in a group played exactly one match against every other team in that group. No match ended in a draw. This is the first stage.

At the end of the first stage, the top four teams from each group advanced to the second stage while the rest got eliminated. At the end of the first stage, top four teams in each group were determined on the basis of total number of matches won by individual teams.

My question is how can we figure out the minimum number of wins needed by any team from one group to proceed into the second stage. What if the numbers are huge i.e. let's say there are $56$ teams in a group? Is there any formula or easy way to determine this value?
Please help !!!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: What are you going to do with ties for fourth place?  Do you want the minimum number of wins guaranteeing advancement or the minimum number of wins making advancement potentially possible?  What have you tried?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1225011/finding-the-minimum-wins-in-a-round-robin-tournament

Comment: I wasn't able to try much as I was not able to think. One of the questions asked was "the number of matches won in the first stage by a team that advanced to the second stage could not be less than" and I guess it means that the minimum number of wins guaranteeing advancement ,right?

Comment: I would read "the number of matches won in the first stage by a team that advanced to the second stage could not be less than" as being the minimum number of wins making advancement potentially possible

Comment: If there are $56$ teams in a group, then each team plays $55$ games, and if half the teams win $28$ games each while the other half win $27$ games each, the teams that win $28$ will progress to the next round.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That is one possibility, but it is also possible that $29$ teams win $41$ games each and $27$ teams win $13$ games each, with one of the $41$-game-winners failing to progress.   Another is the possibility is that $27$ teams win $42$ games each and $29$ teams win $14$ games each, with one of the $14$-game-winners managing to progress.

Answer (score 1):

**Unlucky case:** If there are $n$ teams and $m$ go through, it is possible for $m+1$ teams to win $(n-m-1) + \Big\lfloor\frac m2\Big\rfloor$ games each with one of these teams failing to go through (it cannot be more, as there are not enough games between these $m+1$ teams), so you need to win one more than this i.e. $n-\Big\lceil\frac m2\Big\rceil$ games to be certain of going through

**Lucky case:** If there are $n$ teams and $m$ go through, it is possible for $n-m+1$ teams to win just $\Big\lceil \frac{n-m}{2}\Big\rceil$ games each with one of these managing to go through (there may need to be a tie-break to decide which one)

Examples:

- with $n=8$ teams and $m=4$ going through, you need to win $6$ out of $7$ games to be sure of going through, while you might go through winning $2$ out of $7$ games
- with $n=56$ teams and $m=28$ going through, you need to win $42$ out of $55$ games to be sure of going through, while you might go through winning $14$ out of $55$ games
- with $n=56$ teams and $m=4$ going through, you need to win $54$ out of $55$ games to be sure of going through, while you might go through winning $26$ out of $55$ games

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

For $2n$ teams in the tournament you described $n = 2m$ teams in a group ($n$ is an even integer), by the pigeon principle, the first team have at least $k_1 = \lceil\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2\cdot n}\rceil $ wins to advance. The second, $k_2 = \lceil\dfrac{\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}-k_1}{n-1}\rceil$, and try to find the formula for $k_{m}$, the last team that would advance.